# Three.js 3D rotation of an airplane

Tags: javascript, math, rotation, three.js

I am trying to make a simple airplane flying game.  I'd like the users arrow-keys to rotate a plane around a 360 degree area where up and down is a relative Y-axis to the horizontal position of the airplane.  The left and right arrows should just spin the plane around it's z axis and allow for it to have a new Y-axis position.  My question is - how can I rotate the airplane in a Y-axis that is relative to the new horizontal position?

I have a group called airplane and have done stuff like airplane.rotation.z (for left and right) and airplane.rotation.x (for up and down) - but the x axis isn't along the new horizontal plane. I've also tried accessing the model/mesh within the group with airplane.children[1].matrix.rotation.x to see if this can change the relative Y-axis...This results in the same problem however.  How do I find the relative Y-axis to it's current horizontal position?

My code can be seen on [jsfiddle here](http://bitly.com/SlqdTF)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ctrl-F `?`: No match. At the moment, your question is (almost) a big wall of text, consider restructuring it and formatting it better. Make *clear* what exactly the question is.

Comment: @phant0m - just simplified the question.  Sorry if it wasn't clear before.

Comment: Can you set something up in jsfiddle.net to show your issue?

Comment: @Neil - of course: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc8gH/18/  and thanks in advance for taking a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite frankly, I am having a very difficult time understanding your question, but I think your question is: "How do I use the arrow keys to rotate an object around it's internal z- or x-axis?"

A routine like this one will do that:

```
var _q1 = new THREE.Quaternion();

function rotateOnAxis( object, axis, angle ) {

    _q1.setFromAxisAngle( axis, angle );
    object.quaternion.multiplySelf( _q1 );

}
```

This routine uses quaternions for implementation. This is really no big deal -- you just need to set:

```
object.useQuaternion = true;
```

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lc8gH/20/ .

---

EDIT: You can now use `Object3D.rotateOnAxis( axis, angle );`

three.js r.58

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Sorry my language was so confusing... Really appreciate the help!